# TCP/IP synchronous socket connection from multiple client programs

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, c#-3.0, tcp

I am creating following SocketClient instance from below class and calling from multi-threaded environment as below. Please let me know following code is thread safe or not. Because I have seen responses were mixed up. Some SocketClient received response that need to recevied by another client.

//Calling from multi-threaded environment.

```
SocketClient client=new SocketClient();
client.MakeRequest()
```

===============================================

```
public class SocketClient()
{

byte[] buffer;



public string MakeRequest()
{
            string _response = string.Empty;
            string _xml = string.Empty;
            Socket _sender = null;
            int _connectCount = 0;

            try
            {

                /////////////////////////////Trying to connect to remote host
                while (_connectCount <= 5)
                {
                    _connectCount++;

                    try
                    {
                        if (_sender == null)
                        {
                            _sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                            _sender.ReceiveTimeout = ReceiveTimeout;
                            _sender.SendTimeout = SendTimeout;

                            _sender.Connect(RemoteEP);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {


                        if (_sender != null)
                        {
                            _sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                            _sender.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    if (_sender != null)
                    {
                        if (_sender.Connected || _connectCount > 5)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        _sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        _sender.Close();
                    }
                }


                ///////////////////////////Check connectivity brefore proceed futher
                if (!_sender.Connected)
                {
                    return _response;
                }
                else
                {
                    NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest","L-E-P:"+_sender.LocalEndPoint.ToString()+":R-E-P:"+_sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()+ " Connected: count"+ _connectCount);
                }


                ////////////////////////////Sending data to remote host
                try
                {
                     int bytesSent = 0;
                     bool _isHeaderRead = false;
                     int _bytesRec = 0;

                     _xml = getMessageHeader(xmlStr.Length) + "" + xmlStr;
                     object obydata = (Object)_xml;
                     Encoding oEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
                     byte[] byData = oEncoding.GetBytes(obydata.ToString());

                     //check for 0 based Quotient and Remainder
                     if (Quotient == 0) byData[0] = 0;
                     if (Remainder == 0) byData[1] = 0;

                     if (_sender.Connected)
                     {
                        NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest", "Connected:");
                        bytesSent = _sender.Send(byData);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest" + "::Thread Id :" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "Not Connected:");
                     }

                 //////////////////////////Start receiving data from remote host
                         do
                         {
                             buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                             NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest", "byteSent:" + bytesSent);

                                if (_sender.Connected)
                                {
                                    _bytesRec = _sender.Receive(buffer);
                                    TotbyteReceived = TotbyteReceived + _bytesRec;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest"+"::Thread Id :"+Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "Receiving data , Not conneted:");
                                    break;
                                }

                                NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest" + "::Thread Id :" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "bytesRec:" + _bytesRec + ",TotbyteReceived:" + TotbyteReceived);
                                Array.Resize<byte>(ref buffer, _bytesRec);

                                if (_bytesRec > 0)
                                {
                                    if (!_isHeaderRead)
                                    {
                                       _isHeaderRead = true;
                                        TotResponseByteSize = GetResponseHeaderByteSize(buffer);
                                        RsvbufferStartIndex = 2; // read except header
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        RsvbufferStartIndex = 0;
                                    }

                                    NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest" + "::Thread Id :" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "RsvbufferStartIndex:" + RsvbufferStartIndex);
                                   _response = _response + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, RsvbufferStartIndex, _bytesRec - RsvbufferStartIndex);
                                    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                                    NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest" + "::Thread Id :" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "Txn ID " + txnId + " responseg..data :" + _response);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest", "No data received exiting..:");
                                    break;
                                }

                        }while (TotbyteReceived < TotResponseByteSize);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest", "Exception :" + e.ToString());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest", "Exception :" + e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_sender != null)
                {
                    NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest", "Finally closing socket.");
                    _sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    _sender.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    NetLog.Write("MakeSyncRequest", "Finally socket is null :");
                }
            }

            return _response;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sharing anything between threads?

Comment: Well, if that is really true then there cannot be thread interference. In this code I don't see anything suspicious. Probably the sender is sending the wrong data or callers of MakeRequest are broken.

Comment: What are 'Quotient' and 'Remainder' - they don't seem to be declared in there?

Comment: @MartinJames its like checksum . no affect to code.

Comment: @usr There i am creating a new socket connection for each request and closing it. Is it advisable to do it like that or will use a one open connection for all request and synchronize the requests to use one opened connection.